# What is the correct way of updating a table without having dashboards without data that depend on those tables?

Tags: database, postgresql

I have a dashboard with charts that uses `table_a` information. Every 2 hours I drop the `table_a` and rewrite the new data to it so that my dashboard would have 2-hour uptime. Every these 2 hours there is a 15-minute gap where the data is not available for the dashboard because it is being calculated.

I was wondering what is the correct approach to avoid this 15-minute gap. I am thinking of these steps:

1. Copy the existing table_a to table_a_temp
2. Write the new data to table_a_temp
3. Drop table_a
4. Rename table_a_temp to table_a

Are there any other solutions that are more efficient?

Comment: You can use a materialized view which is refreshed in a single transaction

Comment: So as I understand, I can `create materialized view table_a_mat as select * from table_a`, drop table_a, write new data to newly created `table_a`, and refresh the `table_a_mat`. Will I be able to drop `table_a` when `table_a_mat` is dependant on `table_a`?

Comment: No, you create it only once, then you run `refresh materialized view` in a transaction

Comment: To avoid the 15 minute problem, use `REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY`.